# Error while uploading app to App Store : ITMS -9000 Bundle Error. Invalid XML

Tags: ios, xcode, upload, itunes-store

When I try to upload the App on the App Store I am getting the following Error

> ITMS -9000 Bundle Error. The Bundle is invalid. Invalid XML Character
>   at 0x0010 at index in Info.plist .

I have verified the following things

- Provisioning profile matches with the bundle id.
- Keychain access keys are valid for the certificate.
- Removed extra added features like Applovin Sdk Key from Info.plist
- Current Xcode Version is 5.1.1

Highly Appreciate the help.

[image: Error Image Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

## Check your bundle version

I found the same problem as yours. **The issue was from "Bundle version" in info.plist.**
In my case, the previous version was 1.0 and the version I uploaded was 1.0.2. Even The Bundle version was higher than previous version, Don't know why iTunes won't get it. So to solve this I change back to original uploaded version pattern from 1.0.2 to 1.1 and it worked for me. I hope my answer could help.